# Getting advertisements to properly hide when ABP is enabled

Tags: html, css, adblock

I am building my website with the knowledge that a client wants 2 300x250 ads and 1 728x90 ad. I've added these to the design with the following HTML:

```
<aside class="ad top-left">
    <figure class="ad">
        <img src="{{ url('img/templates/ad_728x90.png') }}" alt="Advertimsent placeholder" />
    </figure>
</aside>
```

This works fine. I've added a little CSS to beautify the ad containers. However, I want to support AdBlock users as well. It looks like trigger on `.ad` causes it, instead of `display: none;` to set `height: 0;`. This is really undesirable as it leaves spare padding and margins behind.

In a nutshell: **How do I get AdBlock Plus to correctly hide my ads?**

Answer (score 0):

Question was answered here:

https://adblockplus.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=31120&p=124757

For some reason, `.advertisement` and `.ad` are not blocked by the EasyList. I ended up using `.advertiser` and `.ad-field` instead. Those will apply the `display: none;`.